# Thumbnails and photo size over Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, image-manipulation, thumbnails

Considering the different sizes of the screen on Windows Mobile devices, which should be the ideal size of a photo that I'm going to show on my WinForm application?

And what about thumbnail? Is there any kind of algorithm to make thumbnail of the images that I'm going to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing photo is depending on your mobile screen resolution and u just have look at default picture control you will get some idea.

you can generate thumbnails first, keep them in separate folder of particular folder,if necessary  load them and display.